# Can I have the mouse indicate I am hovering for resize?

Tags: ubuntu

On OSX Mojave the mouse will change shape to indicate that it is hovering over a resize control at the edge of a window. The shape has horizontal arrows for horizontal resize, vertical arrows for vertical resize and a 45 degree arrows for corner resize. Is there a way I can get the gnome desktop to do the same for Ubuntu 18.04?